# Aws quickstart: vpc configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-vpc, endpoint

I lack experience with aws vpc and quickstart. I would like to use a quickstart ([here)](https://github.com/aws-quickstart/quickstart-illumina-dragen) but what is not clear for me is the strategy use to transfert data from S3 to the instance. According to the image it's seems that a NAT gateway is use but it will be expansive, a S3 gateway endpoint should be better ?
Anyone with knowledge about quickstart/vpc ?

Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: S3 gateway endpoint  is free. So use that. Not sure what is your issue? Check documentation on how to use S3 gateway endpoint .

Comment: Yes i know that S3 gateway endpoint is free, my issue is to know if this quickstart use s3 gateway endpoint or not and if not, how to add it in the cloudformation template ?

Answer (score 1):

The quickstart that you linked **does not** use  S3 gateway endpoint. You have to fork it, and modify it to add the S3 endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you for your answer but i'm not sure what i need to change. In the template of the quickstart the vpc config point to another template :

```
    Resources:
      VPCStack:
        Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
        Properties:
          TemplateURL:
            Fn::Sub:
              - https://${S3Bucket}.s3.${S3Region}.${AWS::URLSuffix}/${QSS3KeyPrefix}submodules/quickstart-aws-vpc/templates/aws-vpc.template.yaml
              - S3Region: !If [UsingDefaultBucket, !Ref 'AWS::Region', !Ref QSS3BucketRegion]
                S3Bucket: !If [UsingDefaultBucket, !Sub '${QSS3BucketName}-${AWS::Region}', !Ref QSS3BucketName]
          Parameters:
            AvailabilityZones:
              Fn::Join:
              - ','
              - !Ref AvailabilityZones
            NumberOfAZs: '2'
            PrivateSubnet1ACIDR: !Ref PrivateSubnet1CIDR
            PrivateSubnet2ACIDR: !Ref PrivateSubnet2CIDR
            PublicSubnet1CIDR: !Ref PublicSubnet1CIDR
            PublicSubnet2CIDR: !Ref PublicSubnet2CIDR
            VPCCIDR: !Ref VPCCIDR
```

In [this vpc template](https://github.com/aws-quickstart/quickstart-aws-vpc/blob/main/templates/aws-vpc.template.yaml) there are these lanes :

```
S3VPCEndpoint:
    Condition: PrivateSubnetsCondition
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPCEndpoint
    Properties:
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          - Action: '*'
            Effect: Allow
            Resource: '*'
            Principal: '*'
      RouteTableIds:
        - !Ref 'PrivateSubnet1ARouteTable'
        - !Ref 'PrivateSubnet2ARouteTable'
        - !If [PrivateSubnets&3AZCondition, !Ref 'PrivateSubnet3ARouteTable', !Ref 'AWS::NoValue']
        - !If [PrivateSubnets&4AZCondition, !Ref 'PrivateSubnet4ARouteTable', !Ref 'AWS::NoValue']
        - !If [AdditionalPrivateSubnetsCondition, !Ref 'PrivateSubnet1BRouteTable', !Ref 'AWS::NoValue']
        - !If [AdditionalPrivateSubnetsCondition, !Ref 'PrivateSubnet2BRouteTable', !Ref 'AWS::NoValue']
        - !If [AdditionalPrivateSubnets&3AZCondition, !Ref 'PrivateSubnet3BRouteTable', !Ref 'AWS::NoValue']
        - !If [AdditionalPrivateSubnets&4AZCondition, !Ref 'PrivateSubnet4BRouteTable', !Ref 'AWS::NoValue']
      ServiceName: !Sub 'com.amazonaws.${AWS::Region}.s3'
      VpcId: !Ref 'VPC'
```

So I thought it was using a s3 gateway endpoint but if not I really don't know what to modify.